# Navigation for One to many relationship does no work in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, one-to-many

I have two entities in my database:Patient and Doctor, which contains one-to-many relationship.Classes are as follows:

```
public partial class Doctor
{
    public Doctor()
    {
        this.Patients = new HashSet<Patient>();
    }
    public int DoctorID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public int SpecialityID { get; set; }

    public virtual Speciality Speciality { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
}



public partial class Patient
{
    public int PatientID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public int DoctorID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
    public virtual PatientAddress PatientAddress { get; set; }
}
```

This is code for adding a patient to a doctor.

```
public ActionResult AddPatient(PatientViewModel patientVM)
    {
        using (PeopleCareEntities PeopleEntities=new PeopleCareEntities())
        {
            PatientAddress patientAddress = Mapper.Map<PatientViewModel, PatientAddress>(patientVM);
            Patient patient = Mapper.Map<PatientViewModel, Patient>(patientVM);
            int currentDoctor = ((Doctor)Session["Doctor"]).DoctorID;
            //problem is here
            Doctor doctor=PeopleEntities.Doctors.Single(a=>a.DoctorID==currentDoctor);
            var doctorPatients = doctor.Patients.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.Email==patientVM.Email);
            if (doctorPatients==null)
            {
                patient.EntryDate = DateTime.Now;
                patient.DoctorID = doctor.DoctorID;
                doctor.Patients.Add(patient);
                PeopleEntities.SaveChanges();
                patientAddress.PatientID = patient.PatientID;
                PeopleEntities.PatientAddresses.Add(patientAddress);
                PeopleEntities.SaveChanges();
                return Json(new { Message = "Patient added successfully !" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { Message="Patient already exist !" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
```

Adding a patient in database works perfectly,but `doctor.Patients has always Count=0.` in debug mode.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading the doctor entity try this:

```
Doctor doctor=PeopleEntities.Doctors.Single(a => a.DoctorID == currentDoctor)
                                    .Include(a => a.Patients);
```